# How to perform Fourier series expansion on a function composed of multiple different sawtooth waves forming a period

Tags: continuous-fourier

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOZSH.jpg)
As shown in the figure, taking 25.25 as T and dividing 2pi into 25.25 parts, a function with 4 different sawteeth forming a period can be obtained. How to expand this function into Fourier series and obtain the expanded formula? Thank you for your answer!

The problem description may be a bit problematic. I am using a spatial light modulator, which consists of several pixels. For example, in a column, I divide it evenly by 2 pixels with a T of 25.25, which means increasing the phase with a step size of 2 pi/25.25, and then taking mod (2 pi/25.25N, 2 pi). Finally, on this column of pixels, I can obtain a cycle consisting of four different jagged edges, which is an integer cycle consisting of 101 pixels. If there is any unclear description of the problem, please leave a message. Thank you.